# c# display and change urls open from client over network

Tags: c#, networking, client

how  display and change url open from client over network 
for example in a network client get internet from default gateway 
and client open url in browser how can show this urls in server and change url to offline data on hard server ?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: yes but i can not find good way

Comment: It is the difference between http:\\ and file:\\.  The connection is different.  HTTP uses a web connection on the server and connects through a web-service on the PC.  File is using shared drives and windows credentials.

Comment: – jdweng i know difference between http:\\ and file:\\ but how monitor ethernet request and change target http to a localhost file server in local network